# In Fody plugin, can I retrieve service from IServiceCollection/DI?

Tags: c#, aop, fody

I am going to adopt https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody as my AOP engine. However, since it is a compile time approach, I have problem on how to retrieve service from IServiceCollection/DI.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance